# How to never get logged out with google sign in on a firebase hosted web app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to develop a Web App which runs on [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) where I log in (once) using the providing google sign in.

The App should use the google APIs to display a variety of informations (email, some special calendars etc).

The idea is to have this Web App run on my tablet 24/7 and never touch it but according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts#jwt_claims) the authentication token will expire after 24 hours which means I need to login every 24 hours.

What is the best way to have a "persistent" login which only expires when the device (or browser) is shut down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at documentation for IoT core. Unless you're using IoT core, that documentation won't apply to you

In regular web apps that use the Firebase JavaScript/Web SDK, the ID tokens is automatically refreshed every hour, and credentials are persisted by the SDK and restored when the app restarts.

In practice this means that the user can sign in once, and stay signed in until you either sign them out explicitly, or until a compelling event forces them to reauthenticate (something like their password being changed, or you disabling their account). Unless something like that happens, you can always get the currently signed in user by [using an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I have a follow up question. In your described scenario the user would have to login when for example the display is shut down for a few days. I was wondering if there is a way to get a persistent token so that you really only have to setup (entering the token) once, or register the display and will always be able to get the data from google (f.e. calendar)

Comment: Once the device is turned on again, the Firebase SDK will refresh the user's sign-in state and get a new ID token for them. If you want something longer lived, you can [use session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) which are valid for up to two weeks. But since you're talking about calling a Google API, there really is very little benefit from that approach and it adds substantial complexity over the approach that the client-side SDKs implement.

Comment: thanks, are there any limits to this approach? Will the Firebase SDK always refresh the token even though the device was off for several month? Its hard to find any documentation about that

Comment: When the SDK detects a new connection and doesn't have an active local ID token, it tries to get one. There's no expiration on this behavior.